# How i can make question preview from textarea like the on Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I have a form similar to the one in which I am writing now:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Body</label>
      <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Your question body here"></textarea>
   </div>
</form>
```

And i have html block which displays textarea preview:

```
<div class="question-preview border-top border-bottom pt-3 pb-3" id="question-preview">
<!--  <p>Default text question</p> -->
<!--  <pre class="prettyprint">var a = 5</pre> -->
 </div>
```

How i can generate html in real time from textarea#body to div#question-preview? Comments in preview block are example of default text and code wrapping. I can't understand how recognize default text from code. I thought i can distinguish it by 4 spacing but my code not works, i'm trying something like this:

```
bodyTextarea.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       const lines = this.value.split(/\n/);

       let code = lines
            .filter((line) => {
                if (/\s{4}/.test(line)) {
                    return line;
                 }
             })
             .reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                 return accumulator + current;
              }, '');

         // FIXME
        if (!/\s{4}/.test(lines[lines.length - 1])) {
             if (previewQuestionArea.querySelector('p')) {
                    previewQuestionArea.querySelector('p').replaceWith(`<p>${lines[lines.length - 1]}</p>`);
             } else {
                 previewQuestionArea.innerHTML = `<p>${lines[lines.length - 1]}</p>`;
               }
             } else {
                if (code !== '') {
                    previewQuestionArea.innerHTML += `<pre class="prettyprint">${code}</pre>`;
                }
            }
        });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery We can define a Regex Pattern and apply a specific styling on that code when we find a Match. In this example I'm expecting as a delimiter 3 quotes : """

For an advanced usage of syntax highliting, you better choose a library like highlight.js or Google Prettify

```js
$('textarea').bind('keyup change', function() {
                
var oldHtml = $(this).val();
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/"""(.*?)"""/g,"<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");                

$(".question-preview").empty().html(newHtml);       

            });
```

```css
.highlight{
color:#B0BF1A;
background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mytext">Body</label>
      <textarea name="body" id="mytext" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">
      </textarea>
   </div>
</form>

<div class="question-preview border-top border-bottom pt-3 pb-3" id="question-preview">
<!--  <p>Default text question</p> -->
<!--  <pre class="prettyprint">var a = 5</pre> -->
 </div>
 </body>
```